# Rails: Show all posts except last post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a section for my latest posts, and a section for all posts. However, my last created post gets shown twice.

In my controller, how do I show all posts except for the last post?

**MainController**

```
 def index
        @post = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
        @latest_post = Post.ordered.first
      end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're querying twice. Instead, query once, and pull the latest post off the result set:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').to_a
  @latest_post = @posts.pop
end
```

I'm not completely sure which side of the results you're considering the "first" record, so if `@posts.pop` appears to give you what you consider the "last" record then use `@posts.shift` to remove the record from the opposite end.

Comment: I get an error: `undefined method 'pop'` -- I'm new to rails

Comment: @GVS Fixed, a `to_a` was required

Comment: With your code in my controller. I'm getting an error in my views code with this line `<% @post.each do |post| %>` I removed the code in my views file and the error still shows, even though the code was removed. So I restarted my server and the error still showed. I replaced your controller code with my original controller code and it works again. I'm not sure why that is happening

Comment: @GVS is `@post` is different to `@posts`

Answer (score 1):

This will not fetch `@latest_post` in `@post`

```
def index
  @latest_post = Post.ordered.first
  @post = Post.where.not(id: @latest_post.id).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Or simply

```
def index
  @latest_post = Post.last
  @posts = Post.where.not(id: @latest_post.id).order('created_at DESC')
end
```